# Python ctypes loading error: undefined symbol

Tags: python, ctypes

I was trying to load a shared library compiled from C source into Python with ctypes. The shared library (named "**libsub.so**" below) used **libusb** libraries. This is what "make" did:

```
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -Werror -g -I../src -I../boot/vnd/fw -I. -fPIC -DLIBUSB_1_0 -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -o libsub.o libsub.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsub.so -o libsub.so libsub.o
```

And I tried Python after that:

```
import ctypes
h = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsub.so')
```

However, I got an error like this

`OSError: ./libsub.so: undefined symbol: libusb_open`

I found "libusb_open" was actually a function of libusb header in "/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h", which was already included in the source of this library "libsub.c".

A few posts in StackExchange talked about such "undefined symbol" errors when loading C++ shared libraries with ctypes, and problems were solved by changing compiler from gcc to g++. However, the source I had was written in C --- so it might be a different situation (actually I tried g++ to compile this source but got a bunch of errors). Can anyone point out what I am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, and I would _love_ to hear if the answer helped you or if you found some other solution.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you should require, in the second line, that your libsub.so be linked together with a pointer to the original libusb.so:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsub.so -lusb -o libsub.so libsub.o
                                  ^^^^^
```

Maybe you also need to specify the path to libusb.so with `-L/path`.